# Keep tablelayoputpanel rows height identical as rows are added dynamically

Tags: winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I have a `TableLayoutPanel` whose rows are set to `autoresize`. It has two `columns`, but `rows` can be added dynamically at run time.

How do I add a `row`, and then have the `height` of each ro`enter code here`w be the same percentage? I tried this code after adding the control:

```
private void BindRawData(int rc) // row number is passed in
{
    var percent = 100 - (tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount * 10);

    tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(grid1, 1, rc);
    
    for(int i = 0; i < tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        var panel = tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles[i];
        panel.SizeType = SizeType.AutoSize;
    }
}
```

The result is a `grid` on top that is really tiny, and the next `grid` takes up almost the whole `panel`.

Comment: If you want all Rows to have the same Height, why have you set the Rows to auto-size instead of a fixed measure? Is the TLP also auto-sizing? What is the content of your TLP? When are you adding Controls to it? -- Since it appears the TLP is not meant to auto-size and empty auto-sizing Rows have `Height = 0`, then the last one fills the client area -- You should describe what's the intended use of this Control

Comment: Content of TLP is a Grid. I didn't want fixed because the number of controls is dynamic and so the number of rows added is only known at runtime

Comment: If the Rows are set to auto-size, then their height is the Height of the hosted Controls. Set the TLP to auto-size (GrowAndShring), so it auto-sizes to its content

Comment: I tried setting autosize and growandshirnk. Doesn't do anything - if there are two rows for example, the top row is small and the second row overwhelmingly dominates in height

Comment: Then TLP's Cells host Controls that have different Height, so it's still not clear what you're working with. In any case, if you setup the TLP's layout in code, you first of all clear the Columns' and Rows' Styles, then set new Styles, then add Controls -- Post an image of the content of this TLP and the code you find in the Form's `.Designer.cs` file